Superset collapse a native filter by default on load
I have an Apache Superset dashboard with text boxes that redirect to different dashboards with respective charts when clicking on the markdown component. I was able to use '&expand_filters=0' in the URL to collapse the filter when redirecting to a dashboard. Now, we have a native filter in the main dashboard, but I am unable to collapse the filter by default when the dashboard loads. Are there any JSON metadata keys or any other ways to collapse the filter by default?
I tried this config in JSON Metadata
{
    "native_filter_configuration": {
        "filters": [
            {
                "id": "filter_id_1",
                "visibility": "collapsed"
            }
        ]
    }
}

but this doesn't seem to work
